# Hidden nodes doesn't see pg2 groups

Tags: erlang, distributed

I have several erlang nodes running in one cluster. By some reason I want to run some nodes with `-hidden` key. But if I do so, hidden nodes does not see `pg2` groups created on other nodes. Is there any way to make hidden notes see them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No experience with `pg2`, but if a hidden node was able to join a `pg2` group, that would make processes of an hidden node visible with `pg2:get_members(Name)` call. From [the Erlang documentation about hidden nodes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id83549), this sounds like "disturbing" the other nodes, which is what the hidden node functionality is trying to avoid. So, from a glance, this looks by design to me.

Comment: Yes, I've already found that. pg2 used `nodes()` function which returns only _visible_ (not _all connected_) nodes.